# WordPress custom slug (endpoint) and compare all links

Tags: php, wp-query, permalinks, slug, endpoints

I work on the one i18n function. It will work with subdir. For example: `eg.com/hello-world/en`

For this I'm support `EP_ALL` for the WP custom endpoints.

```
function lang_add_endpoints(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint('en', EP_ALL);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('de', EP_ALL);
} 
add_action('init', 'lang_add_endpoints');
```

For example:

```
eg.com/en
eg.com/page/en
eg.com/post(hello-world)/fr
eg.com/10/11/2018/de
and more...
```

It is well done.
Now, how can I add `"/en/ or /de/ or /any/"` slug all WP links if the query has `"en"`.

For example:

I have COOKIE: (I have an idea just I say for my quest)

```
if($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en') :

<a href="eg.com/example/en" >Example</a>
<a href="eg.com/05/11/2018/en" >Example</a>
<a href="eg.com/category/news/en" >Example</a>

elseif($_COOKIE['lang'] == 'de') :

<a href="eg.com/05/11/2018/de" >Example</a>
<a href="eg.com/tags/computer/de" >Example</a>

endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the API functions that generate links have filters to let you alter the output. Here's a quick example that covers most of them:

```
function wpd_endpoint_links( $url ){
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['lang'] ) ){
        $url = $url . $_COOKIE['lang'] . '/';
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'attachment_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'post_type_archive_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'day_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'month_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
add_filter( 'year_link', 'wpd_endpoint_links' );
```